# Перевод каретки на новую строку с учетом количества символов табуляции в предыдущей строке

Tags: delphi

```
if (Key=VK_RETURN) then
begin
  Memo1.SetFocus;
  keybd_event(8, 0, 0, 0);
  Memo1.SetSelTextBuf(#13#10);

  if Pos(#9#9#9,Memo1.Lines[Memo1.CaretPos.Y-1])=1 then
    Memo1.SetSelTextBuf(#9#9#9)
  else
    if Pos(#9#9,Memo1.Lines[Memo1.CaretPos.Y-1])=1 then
      Memo1.SetSelTextBuf(#9#9)
    else
      if Pos(#9,Memo1.Lines[Memo1.CaretPos.Y-1])=1 then
        Memo1.SetSelTextBuf(#9)
end;
```

Задача выполнена следующим образом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

правильнее будет так:

```
if (Key=VK_RETURN) then
begin
  Memo1.SetFocus;
  keybd_event(8, 0, 0, 0);
  Memo1.SetSelTextBuf(#13#10);

  if Pos(#9#9#9,Memo1.Text)=1 then
    Memo1.SetSelTextBuf(#9#9#9) 
  else
    if Pos(#9#9,Memo1.Text)=1 then
      Memo1.SetSelTextBuf(#9#9) 
    else
      if Pos(#9,Memo1.Text)=1 then
        Memo1.SetSelTextBuf(#9)
end;
```

Comment: Нет, мой код изначально неправильный, и поменять местами количество "#9" не поможет. Хотя так и правильней, но работает некорректно в любом случае. Работает правильно только первая строка, остальные отталкиваются от количества табов в первой строке.